# How can I set a pattern in a DBAppender?

Tags: logback

I using logback and put a pettern into a dbappender, but it doesn´t work.

```
    <appender name="DB" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender">
    <connectionSource
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.db.DriverManagerConnectionSource">
        <driverClass>net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver</driverClass>
        <url>jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:1433/granica</url>
        <user>java</user>
        <password>java</password>
    </connectionSource>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

someone know how to fix that?
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can't put a pattern in a DBAppender:**

*"The DBAppender inserts logging events into three database tables in a format independent of the Java programming language.*

*These three tables are logging_event, logging_event_property and logging_event_exception. They must exist before DBAppender can be used. Logback ships with SQL scripts that will create the tables."*

***Alternative solution:*** If you realy need this pattern, then you should ***create an extra dataBbase table/view/sql that generaties that output for you***, based on the existing tables. This can be done with a simple SQL, View or Triggers. Use standard SQL to create the output you need.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to customize the formatted message easily enough by defining a couple of custom classes, one extending the `DBAppender` and the other implementing the `ILoggingEvent` interface:

```java
package com.mypackage;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.util.Map;

import org.slf4j.Marker;

import ch.qos.logback.classic.Level;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ILoggingEvent;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.IThrowableProxy;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LoggerContextVO;

/**
 * 
 * @author PJ_Finnegan
 * 
 *         To override the default DBAppender with a custom FORMATTED_MESSAGE
 *
 */
public class MdcDbAppender extends DBAppender {

    @Override
    protected void subAppend(ILoggingEvent event, Connection connection, PreparedStatement insertStatement)
            throws Throwable {
        // use a special event with custom formatted message
        MdcLoggingEvent customEvent = new MdcLoggingEvent(event);
        super.subAppend(customEvent, connection, insertStatement);
    }

}

/**
 * 
 * @author PJ_Finnegan
 * 
 *         To override the getFormattedMessage() method prepending MDC info
 *
 */
class MdcLoggingEvent implements ILoggingEvent {

    private ILoggingEvent mOrigEvent;

    public MdcLoggingEvent(ILoggingEvent origEvent) {
        mOrigEvent = origEvent;
    }

    @Override
    public String getThreadName() {
        return mOrigEvent.getThreadName();
    }

    @Override
    public Level getLevel() {
        return mOrigEvent.getLevel();
    }

    @Override
    public String getMessage() {
        return mOrigEvent.getMessage();
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] getArgumentArray() {
        return mOrigEvent.getArgumentArray();
    }

    @Override
    public String getFormattedMessage() {
        // add my MDC info as a prefix
        String mdcVals[] = new String[] { "NA", "NA", "NA" };
        Map<String, String> mpm = mOrigEvent.getMDCPropertyMap();
        if (mpm != null) {
            int i = 0;
            for (String key : new String[] { "jobName", "jobInstanceId", "jobExecutionId" }) {
                if (mpm.containsKey(key)) {
                    mdcVals[i] = mpm.get(key);
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
        return String.format("[%s-%s-%s] ", mdcVals[0], mdcVals[1], mdcVals[2]) + mOrigEvent.getFormattedMessage();
    }

    @Override
    public String getLoggerName() {
        return mOrigEvent.getLoggerName();
    }

    @Override
    public LoggerContextVO getLoggerContextVO() {
        return mOrigEvent.getLoggerContextVO();
    }

    @Override
    public IThrowableProxy getThrowableProxy() {
        return mOrigEvent.getThrowableProxy();
    }

    @Override
    public StackTraceElement[] getCallerData() {
        return mOrigEvent.getCallerData();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasCallerData() {
        return mOrigEvent.hasCallerData();
    }

    @Override
    public Marker getMarker() {
        return mOrigEvent.getMarker();
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getMDCPropertyMap() {
        return mOrigEvent.getMDCPropertyMap();
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getMdc() {
        return mOrigEvent.getMdc();
    }

    @Override
    public long getTimeStamp() {
        return mOrigEvent.getTimeStamp();
    }

    @Override
    public void prepareForDeferredProcessing() {
        mOrigEvent.prepareForDeferredProcessing();
    }

}
```

This way the `LOGGING_EVENT.FORMATTED_MESSAGE` column values on the DB will have the string `[jobName-jobInstanceId-jobExecutionId]` (whose value I had previously put in MDC) prepended:

| TIMESTMP | FORMATTED_MESSAGE |
| --- | --- |
| 1635255763784 | [test-2760-3980] HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed. |

Of course you want to use your custom class in your `logback.xml` file instead of the stock DBAppender:

```xml
    <!-- DB appender -->
    <!-- use our custom class to override the FORMATTED_MESSAGE default pattern -->
    <!-- <appender name="ORADB" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender"> -->
    <appender name="ORADB" class="com.mypackage.MdcDbAppender">
        <connectionSource
...
```

Nothing prevents from overriding the `ILoggingEvent.getFormattedMessage()` method with more elaborated manipulations.